# Numpy: How do I get inside an "overflow encountered in exp"?

Tags: python, numpy, overflow

First post, please be gentle!

I am trying to do root finding on an exponential function `1/(np.exp((j-w)/x)-1)`, and I find I keep getting the `RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp`.

I understand this comes from the limitations on float64, but I can't seem to insert code to help understand where this is coming from.  I have tried to include some `try...except OverflowError` blocks to give me a peek inside where this keeps happening, but it never seems to catch this.

I have ideas on how to handle it, as long as I can get my code to do something different when it encounters overflows.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack! What IDE are you using? My approach is to hook into the library  code and debug from there instead of `try/except` on the user side. Before I answer, is that an acceptable solution path for you?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!  Im using vim to write code and run it with my python on my terminal.  I would tell you that is acceptable if I know what that meant!  Sorry, I have a very ad hoc understanding of coding based mostly on trial and error, rather than a formal education of computer systems!

Comment: Hi ! Could you post a minimal example of code, we can run, so we can give a precise answer?

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is also helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi @WindowLicker! No worries on understanding, we all start somewhere. Unfortunately, I would need to research more to get you proper code that hooks into runtime procedures. However, if you can download an IDE, say [PyCharm Community Edition](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/), I can help you work through a debugger. Let me know!

Comment: Thank you guys so much for your help.  You have no idea how frustrating all this was.  I really appreciate the responsiveness!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the problem is that you cannot figure out when warning happens. To do that use `try`/`except` but in slightly modified way:

```py
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("error")
...
try:
    1/(np.exp((j-w)/x)-1)
except RuntimeWarning:
    print(j)
    print(w)
    print(x)
    print((j-w)/x)
```

This should give a hint, there the problem lies

Comment: THIS!  Thank you so much.  I couldnt figure out how to get my code to tell me when it was encountering errors.  Why do all my problems have simple solutions that I can never see?  Thanks, rpoleski