# "RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp", but not when using an array

Tags: python, numpy

I am implementing the following formula:

[image: survival function, eq. 49 from doi: 10.1063/1.447954]

in Python (with SciPy and NumPy). I wrote the following expression:

```
def fokker_plank_solution_1_sur(t, k, c, x_0):
    if k == 0 & c == 0:
        pass
    
    else:
        print("Case 2")
        t_1 = (k - c)/(k - 2*c)
        t_2 = np.exp((k * x_0 + k*(k - 2*c)*t))
        t_3 = erfc((x_0 + 2 * (k - c) * t)/(np.sqrt(4*t)))
        t_4 = 0.5
        t_5 = erfc((- x_0 + 2 * c * t)/np.sqrt(4 * t))
        t_6 = k/(k - (2 * c))
        t_7 = np.exp(2 * c * x_0)
        t_8 = erfc((x_0 + 2*c*t)/(np.sqrt(4*t)))
        
        y = t_1 * t_2 * t_3 + t_4 * (t_5 - t_6 * t_7 * t_8)
        
        return y
```

Case 1:
If I am using the following conditions, I am getting "good" numbers (t_2 = 1.94e+05) and the plot[image: matplotlib of the survivalrate]

```
D = .25
x_val = np.linspace(1,500,250)
c = 0
x_0 = 5

for k in [.8]:
    y_val = fokker_plank_solution_1_sur(x_val * D, k, c, x_0)
                                                   |      |

    # print(np.concatenate((x_val.reshape([250,1]), y_val.reshape([250,1])), axis = 1))
    
    plt.plot(x_val, y_val)
```

Case 2:
However, if I am just putting this in the console,

```
fokker_plank_solution_1_sur(np.array((50.0)) * .25, 10, 0, 0.8)
                                                     |       |
```

I get the return

```
t_2 = np.exp((k * x_0 + k*(k - 2*c)*t))

RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
```

After some search, I found t_2 is just getting too big, to be further processed ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61380331/numpy-how-do-i-get-inside-an-overflow-encountered-in-exp),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17000632/python-how-to-determine-largest-smallest-int-long-float-complex-numbers-my-syste)), t_2 is then

```
e^1258.0
```

-> So the question now is, why can python calculate numbers, when using a NumPy array indirectly (case 1), but not when using the NumPy array directly (case 2)?
Thank you for reading this far.

Comment: Solution: I found the bug, it is the guy in front of the screen. I switched the arguments, in case 1 I wrote: 
fokker_plank_solution_1_sur(np.array((50.0)) * .25, 0.8, 0, 10)
and in case 2:
fokker_plank_solution_1_sur(np.array((50.0)) * .25, 10, 0, 0.8)
That caused all the trouble. Sorry for the hustle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you tell NumPy to handle errors. You can control it with [seterr](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html) or [errstate](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.errstate.html).

For example:

```
>>> with np.errstate(all='ignore'):
...    print(fokker_plank_solution_1_sur(np.array((50.0)) * .25, 10, 0, 0.8))
nan


>>> with np.errstate(all='warn'):
...     print(fokker_plank_solution_1_sur(np.array((50.0)) * .25, 10, 0, 0.8))

RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
  t_2 = np.exp((k * x_0 + k * (k - 2 * c) * t))
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  y = t_1 * t_2 * t_3 + t_4 * (t_5 - t_6 * t_7 * t_8)
nan


>>> with np.errstate(all='raise'):
...     print(fokker_plank_solution_1_sur(np.array((50.0)) * .25, 10, 0, 0.8))
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [...]
  t_2 = np.exp((k * x_0 + k * (k - 2 * c) * t))
FloatingPointError: overflow encountered in exp
```

You are likely using a different setting in your program and when you call the function from the console.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Learned a bit or two about the workings of NumPy.